# harvard kluwer bibliography, missing article titles

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, harvard-style

I am trying to do the bibliography style to my liking, and I almost succeeded but for some reason I cannot get the article titles to show up. I have author - year - journal - volume/issue/page and I want  author - year - TITLE - journal - volume/issue/page.

I'm using the harvard package with modified kluwer style for my references, I have found it works best for the exact style I want. I've modified a few things in it though:

Added:

```
    FUNCTION {format.url}
{ url empty$
    { "" }
    {   
        " Available from:~\url{" * url * "}" *
    }
  if$
}
```

Changed:

```
FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { "Vol." volume tie.or.space.connect
      series empty$
    'skip$
    { " of " * series emphasize * }
      if$
      "volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}
```

and

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
    { "Vol. " volume field.or.null
      number empty$
        'skip$
        { "(" number * ")" * *
          volume empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
          if$
        }
      if$
      pages empty$
        'skip$
        { duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ format.pages }
        { ",~p.~" * pages n.dashify * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
```

And my article formatting looks like this:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  list.label.output
  " " list.year * output.nonnull
  new.block
  author "author" item.check
  if$
  title.field field.used =
    { skip$ }
    { format.title "title" output.check }
  if$
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" duplicate$ item.check
      " " * format.vol.num.pages * output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}
```

When running bibtex I get the error:

You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry arnould while executing---line 1362 of file kluwer.bst You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry arnould while executing---line 1362 of file kluwer.bst " 2005" is a string literal, not a function, for entry arnould while executing---line 1362 of file kluwer.bst You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry arnould while executing---line 1362 of file kluwer.bst ptr=1, stack= Consumer culture theory (cct): twenty years of research ---the literal stack isn't empty for entry arnould while executing---line 1362 of file kluwer.bst   and so on...

Help please? I'm at my wits end...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after numerous tries on what could be wrong, I've managed to force the code to work. The new article function:

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  list.label.output
  " " list.year * output.nonnull
  author "author" output.check
  if$
  title.field field.used =
    { skip$ }
    { format.title "title" output }
  if$
  crossref missing$
    { " " journal emphasize "journal" duplicate$ item.check
      " " * format.vol.num.pages * output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}
```

Looks like item.check was causing the problems...